# Which Java API from the Azure SDK to manage PostgreSQL servers?

Tags: java, azure, security, networking, azure-sdk

I can't find the Java API from the Azure SDK to manage PostgreSQL firewall rules.

The REST API is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/firewallrules).

Does anyone know which Maven dependency to use?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you can find source code for Java SDK for PostgreSQL here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/postgresql.

Comment: Yes, thanks, looks like the best option, but it doesn't seem to be maintained, I'll dig into the source code to see how they deal with the REST API, thanks again.